# Javascript - How to return the correct value with the multiplication of all the elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6, multiplication

What I'm trying to do here it's multiply all the elements of the array A. With these values: [1,2,0,-5]it should returns 0... but it returns 1. What I'm doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
function solution(A){
    let multi = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
        multi *= A[i]
    } 

    if(multi = 30){
        return 1
    } else if (multi = -30){
        return -1
    } else if (multi = 0){
        return 0
    } else{
        console.log("hey hey");
    }
}

solution(A = [1,2,0,-5])
```

Comment: Your if statements use a single equality sign which is the assignment operator. Replace `=` with `==`.

Comment: `i` should start at 0 instead of 1. It should also be declared, so `for (let i = 1; …`. The call should be `solution([1,2,0,-5])` without `A = `, because JavaScript doesn’t have named arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Ry- . You solved the problem. Can you answer for me to make your answer the correct one?

Comment: `=` assigns a value, returning always true. You need to compare values instead.

Comment: Those were code cleanup/future correctness tips. @ChristianIvicevic’s comment should be the one that actually solved *this* problem.

Comment: @Ry- I don't mind someone else posting their answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is starting at `1` - JavaScript arrays (and arrays in many other languages) are 0-indexed, so start at `0`. Your `if` conditions are also wrong - use the comparison operator `==` not the assignment operator `=`.

```
function solution(A){
    let multi = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        multi *= A[i]
    } 

    if(multi == 30){
        return 1
    } else if (multi == -30){
        return -1
    } else if (multi == 0){
        return 0
    } else{
        console.log("hey hey");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays start at 0 not 1.
Anyway since that is causing trouble you should use the "reduce" function to multiple the elements of an array as this avoids the need worrying about the indices.

```
let mult = A.reduce((a,b)=>a*b);
```

With the if there is an assignment not a comparison. 
if(multi=30) then tests whether multi is non-zero, which it is because it is 30. 
One way to avoid this problem is putting the constant on the left:-

```
  if(30 === multi){
        return 1
    } else if (-30 ===multi){
        return -1
    } else if (0===multi){
        return 0
    } else{
        console.log("hey hey");
    }
```

Also passing values to functions is by position. No need to name the parameter, it is incorrect to do that.

```
solution([1,2,0,-5]);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that reduce starts at 0, so your current suggestion will always yield 0 as a result. Pass 1 as the start value for the accumulator.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: reduce starts with the first two elements without an explicit initial value. It does make a difference vs. the loop in the question when passing an empty array, though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(A){
  const mult = A.reduce((a, b) => a*b);
  return mult == 30 ? 1 : mult == -30 ? -1 : 0;
}

console.log(solution(A = [1,2,0,-5]));
```